# bash: bundle: command not found even though bundler is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am hosting a Rails app on AWS EC2 instance and am deploying my application with Capistrano. During deployment I have been able to solve errors by installing missing tools like Monit. However, I'm stumped by this error: `puma stderr: bash: bundle: command not found`. I see bundler is installed on the server, but when i type `bundle` the terminal says `Could not locate Gemfile`. I have even tried reinstalling bundler `gem install bundler` but bundle command is still not recognized. I have listed details about my deployment target below. I'm not sure what to do and would appreciate any help.

gem environment returns:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.5 (2019-10-01 patchlevel 114) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/ubuntu/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/ubuntu/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
     - /home/ubuntu/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-document"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin
     - /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/libexec
     - /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /snap/bin
```

`echo $PATH` returns

```
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims:/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

`which gem` returns

```
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/gem
```

`locate bundle` returns

```
/home/ubuntu/.gem/specs/rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/bundler-1.17.1.gemspec
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/bundle
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/bundler
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/bundle
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/bundler
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/build_metadata.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/capistrano.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/cli
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/cli.rb
...
```

Comment: What is the user that is executing the scripts? What is the output of `w`?

This might be a permissions issue.

Comment: this is what i see when typing `w` on server: `USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
ubuntu   pts/0    139.28.216.154   19:17    1.00s  0.03s  0.00s w`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like some puma setting was overwritten. I added the following line to `deploy.rb` : `set :rbenv_map_bins, %w{rake gem bundle ruby rails puma pumactl}` to get past this error.

Link to the solution:
https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-puma/issues/206

Answer (score 0):

If you use bundler, you should add `capistrano-bundler`. See [GitHub issue](https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-puma/issues/149)